# How can I pass the output from each of the print statements into tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

```
# Create a class DataExplore
class DataExplore:

    # Define initialization method
    def __init__(self, filepath):
        self.filepath = filepath
        self.data = pd.read_csv(filepath)

        
    # Define desc_stats method, with argument
    def desc_stats(self):
        # Return a description data_as_csv
        return self.data.describe()
    
    def miss_values(self):
        return self.data.isnull().sum().sum() 
    
    def fill_missing(self):
        fill = self.data.interpolate(method='linear', axis=0).ffill().bfill()
        return fill
    
    def correl(self):
        return self.data.corr(method = 'pearson')
    
    ### linear regression
    def ln_reg(self):
        self.data = self.data.interpolate(method='linear', axis=0).ffill().bfill()
        x = self.data.iloc[:, 2:]
        y = self.data.iloc[:,1]
        model = sm.OLS(y, x).fit()
        return model.summary()

## Passed the cvs file to the class DataExplore
data_explore = DataExplore('project_data.csv')

#print(data_explore.desc_stats())

#print (data_explore.correl())

#print(data_explore.miss_values())

#print(data_explore.fill_missing())

print(data_explore.ln_reg())
```

Comment: There is no tkinter code in your example. What do you mean by "pass into tkinter"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the context manager `redirect_stdout` to redirect the print output towards a data structure.
Then display the content of the data structure to a tkinter window:

[image]

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
import tkinter as tk


class Txt:

    def __init__(self):
        self._data = []

    def write(self, val):
        self._data.append(str(val))

    def __str__(self):
        return ''.join(self._data)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    txt = Txt()

    with redirect_stdout(txt):
        print('this text')
        print('is being redirected')
        print('to a Txt object')
        print('than displayed in a tkinter window')

    print('this goes to the console')

    root = tk.Tk()
    text_w = tk.Text(root)
    text_w.insert('1.0', str(txt))
    text_w.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

    root.mainloop()
```